# Text-based casino game

Tags: c++, game

I have made this small text-based casino game in C++. How could I improve it? Be as picky as you'd like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// General functions
void bankrupt();

// Roulette functions
void roulette01();
void roulette02();
void rouletteWin();
void rouletteLoss();

// Slots functions
void slots01();
void slots02();

// General variables
int invalid = 1;
int input;
int dollars = 50;

// Roulette variables
int bet = 0;
char cColour;
int iColour;
int actualColour;

// Slots variables
int randSlots01;
int randSlots02;
int randSlots03;

int main() {

    srand (time(NULL));

    while (invalid == 1) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n Welcome to the Casino! What would you like to play?" << endl;
        cout << "\n 1. Roulette" << endl;
        cout << "\n 2. Slots" << endl;
        cout << "\n 3. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "\n> ";
        cin >> input;
        switch (input) {

            case 1:
                input = 1;
                roulette01();

            case 2:
                slots01();

            case 3:
                exit(0);

            default:
                cout << "\n That was invalid input!" << endl;
                cout << "\n ";
                system("pause");
                invalid = 1;

        }
    }
}

void roulette01() {

    if (dollars <= 0) {
        bankrupt();
    }

    system("cls");
    cout << "\n Roulette" << endl;
    cout << "\n You have " << dollars << " dollars!" << endl;
    cout << "\n Enter 1 to place a bet. Enter 2 to exit to the main menu." << endl;
    cout << "\n> ";
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {

        case 1:
            roulette02();

        case 2:
            main();

    }
}

void roulette02() {

    cout << "\n Enter how much you would like to bet." << endl;
    cout << "\n> ";
    cin >> bet;

    if (bet > dollars) {
        cout << "\n You don't have enough money for that bet!" << endl;
        cout << "\n ";
        system("pause");
        roulette02();
    }

    cout << "\n Would you like to bet on red or black?" << endl;
    cout << "\n Enter r for red. Enter b for black." << endl;
    cout << "\n> ";
    cin >> cColour;

    if (cColour == 'r') {
        iColour = 1;
    }

    else {
        iColour = 2;
    }

    actualColour = rand() % 2;

    if (actualColour == iColour) {
        rouletteWin();
    }

    else {
        rouletteLoss();
    }

}

void rouletteWin() {

    dollars = dollars + bet;
    cout << "\n You won " << bet << " dollars!" << endl;
    cout << "\n ";
    system("pause");
    roulette01();

}

void rouletteLoss() {

    dollars = dollars - bet;
    cout << "\n You lost " << bet << " dollars!" << endl;
    cout << "\n ";
    system("pause");
    roulette01();

}

void slots01() {

    if (dollars <= 0) {
        bankrupt();
    }

    system("cls");
    cout << "\n Slots" << endl;
    cout << "\n You have " << dollars << " dollars!" << endl;
    cout << "\n Enter 1 to play. Enter 2 to exit to the main menu." << endl;
    cout << "\n> ";
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {

        case 1:
            slots02();

        case 2:
            main();

    }
}

void slots02() {

    randSlots01 = rand() % 3;
    randSlots02 = rand() % 3;
    randSlots03 = rand() % 3;

    if (randSlots01 == randSlots02 && randSlots02 == randSlots03) {
        dollars = dollars + 10;
        cout << "\n You won 10 dollars!" << endl;
        cout << "\n ";
        system("pause");
        slots01();
    }

    else {
        dollars--;
        cout << "\n You lost 1 dollar!" << endl;
        cout << "\n ";
        system("pause");
        slots01();
    }
}

void bankrupt() {

    dollars = 50;
    cout << "\n You have gone bankrupt! Time to start over." << endl;
    cout << "\n ";
    system("pause");
    main(); 

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Your naming needs a lot of work. In particular it's a very bad idea to name your entities with numeric suffixes, as that doesn't explain at all what they're doing (it shows they're related but not how, and definitely not how they differ from each other in function).
- All your variables are global. This is very bad form. Variables should have the smallest possible scope, so it's plainly evident where they're used and what they're used for. There are a number of ways to deal with global state; but at this level there probably should just be a `struct` that gets passed around.
- You've got some unnecessary code. There's no reason for `input = 1;` in the first case.
- You shouldn't use `exit(0)` unless you have a reason to. `return` works perfectly well for returning from `main()`.
- Don't rely on `system()` for controlling the user interface. It makes your code impossible to port. At the very least, make helper functions for each of the tasks so that you just have to replace the code once in each helper function.
- Your program crashes if the user does not input an integer at the main menu.
- The sub-functions, `roulette01()` and `slots01()`, should not call `main()`. `main()` already has a loop in it, so you can just `return;` from them to get back to `main()`.
- Similarly, `roulette01()` and `slots01()` should be structured to include a loop, so that you don't have functions recursively calling each other.
- Ideally you ought to completely separate the logic of each game from the user interface. One function does the logic, another function calls it and displays the results.

Answer (score 12):

I have found a couple of things that could help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  It's an alarmingly common thing for new C++ programmers to do.

### Don't call `main`

According to the C++ ISO standard section 3.6.1

> The function `main` shall not be used within a program.

So your program is technically malformed.  Rather than doing it that way, simply return to `main` if needed.

### Avoid the use of global variables

I see that `invalid` is used only within `main` but it's declared as s global variable. It's generally better to explicitly pass variables your function will need or declare them within the appropriately smallest possible scope rather than using the vague implicit linkage of a global variable.

### Don't use `system("pause")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `cls` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a seperate functions `cls()` and `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++.  For example:

```
void pause() {
    getchar();
}
```

### Use a menu object or at least a common menu function

In a number of places in your code, you have something like a menu.  Your code presents a couple of options and then asks the user to pick one based on an input number. Rather than repeating that code in many places, it would make sense to make it generic.  Only the prompt strings actually change, but the underlying logic of presenting the choices and asking for input are all the same.  It looks like you're a beginning programmer, and so perhaps you haven't learned about objects yet, but this kind of repeated task with associated data is really well-suited to *object-oriented programming* and that's something that C++ is very good at expressing.

### Use better function names

The names you've chosen are not too bad, but `slots01` and `slots02` are poor names.  We can infer that they have something to do with slots, but what?  The name should suggest that.

### Restructure the code

The `bankrupt()` routine is called when the user attempts to play slots or roulette, but it would make more sense to put those calls within `main`.

### Consider using a better random number generator

You are currently using

```
actualColour = rand() % 2;
```

There are two problems with this approach. One is that the low order bits of the random number generator are not particularly random, so neither will `actualColour` be.  On my machine, there's a slight but measurable bias toward 0 with that.  The second problem is that it's not thread safe because `rand` stores hidden state.  A better solution, if your compiler and library supports it, would be to use the [C++11 `std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).  It looks complex, but it's actually pretty easy to use.

Comment: Regarding random number generation, I highly recommend Stephan Lavavej's (Microsoft) talk on why rand() is bad - he also shows how a novice can easily use the C++ standard library's tools as mentioned in the post.